# How to make a dictionary from complex data in a text file with different values corresponding to the same key?

Tags: python

here is the txt file

[image: here is the txt file]

I need to make a dictionary called "patients'" that will output a dictionary as so:

```
{1: [['2022-06-01', 37.2, 72, 16, 120, 80, 97], ['2022-09-15', 37.5, 73, 18, 125, 82, 96]], 2: [['2022-06-10', 36.9, 69, 18, 123, 80, 96], ['2023-01-03', 37.1, 71, 19, 124, 81, 97]], 3: [['2022-08-05', 37.3, 74, 20, 126, 83, 95], ['2023-03-01', 37.4, 75, 18, 123, 79, 98]]}
```

what I tried

[image: what I tried]

This is what is returned

```
{1: [['2022-09-15', 37.5, 73, 18, 125, 82, 96]], 2: [['2023-01-03', 37.1, 71, 19, 124, 81, 97]], 3: [['2023-03-01', 37.4, 75, 18, 123, 79, 98]]}
```

Only the second values for each key is returned, not both

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code, errors or sample in- and outputs. Copy-paste the relevant parts into the question, and format it as a code block. Pictures of text are non-copy-pasteable, non-searchable, and can't be read properly by screenreaders. See also [this question and its responses](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: It looks like `line_num` is defined but never used.

Answer (score 0):

Use a defaultdict. The gist of using it in your code is as follows:

```
from collections import defaultdict


data = defaultdict(list)
for ...
   ...
   data[patientId].append([date, temp, hr, ...])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in the last line, you're overwriting the first value of patients[patientId] with the second value. I recommend using a defaultdict and appending to it.